# Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) error shown in IntelliJ

Tags: java, java-11

While running a program in IntelliJ which was running earlier but now this error pops up:

[image]

and this error is shown

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of following reasons:

1. The incorrect or failed installation of application that may have left invalid entries in your Windows registry;
2. The virus or malware attack;
3. The improper system shutdown;
4. Corrupted or deleted system files.

You need to either restart the program or shutdown the system once and try to start the program again.
If that doesn't help re-install the application again.